# can a script with only statements(no defs) be imported

Tags: import

All,

If a script has a series of executable statements but no defined functions can it be imported and used in another script?
If so how? How to call it?

thanks

jayk

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,I found the answer to the above question

A .py file with only statements.To get it's output in another script just import it:- *import file name (without .py extention)* as in the example below.

thanks

jayk

```
#--------personalInfo.py--this file will be imported----------     
name="Don"
surname="Triumph"
print name +" "+surname

# importScript.py#----------------------------------
def callScript():
    import personalInfo
callScript()

# result- Don Triumph
```